# Angular named router outlet link not working

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm facing some problems to make a link to a named router outlet work on Angular.

Here goes the most important part of the code:

**app-routing-module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {FirstComponent} from './first/first.component';
import {SecondComponent} from './second/second.component';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import {DefaultSideBarComponent} from './default-side-bar/default-side-bar.component';
import {AlternativeSideBarComponent} from './alternative-side-bar/alternative-side-bar.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent},
  { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/first', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
  { path: 'alternative-side-bar', component: AlternativeSideBarComponent, outlet: 'sidebar'},
  { path: '', component: DefaultSideBarComponent, outlet: 'sidebar'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a routerLink="first" routerLinkActive="active">first</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="second" routerLinkActive="active">second</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="side-bar">
    <router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
</div>
```

And here a print-screen just to make things more clear:

[image]

The problems I'm facing are on the links inside the sidbears components.

**default-side-bar.component.html**

```html
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{sidebar: ['alternative-side-bar']}}]" >Change Bar</a>
<p>default-side-bar works!</p>
```

This link is working ok.

**alternative-side-bar.component.html**

```html
<a [routerLink]="['',{outlets:{sidebar: ['']}}]" >Change Bar</a>
<p>alternative-side-bar works!</p>
```

Now this is the link were I'm having problems. It is resolving to this:

```
http://localhost:4200/first(sidebar:)
```

And obviously, it doesn't work. It generates the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
```

Is it possible to use a default root path '' to a named outlet and have some working link pointing to it?

[StackBlitz if you want to try it out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-named-outlet?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**Note:**

If I use this:

```html
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{sidebar: ['']}}]" >Change Bar</a>
```

The result is even worst with a nested awkward outlet link:

```
http://localhost:4200/first(sidebar:alternative-side-bar/(sidebar:))
```

Comment: So the expectation is when we click Change Bar link it should reload same component?

Comment: @Chellappanவ No, it should load the other sidebar. If the default sidebar is been displayed, the alternative sidebar should be loaded and if the alternative sidebar is been displayed than the default should be loaded. Each sidebar points to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [routerLink] as shown below.

**alternative-side-bar.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['',{outlets:{sidebar: []}}]">Change Bar</a>
<p>alternative-side-bar works!</p>
```

Comment: It seems to work but the problem with this approach is that the default sidebar outlet now will have a named path so the application starts with sidebar outlet on the path and if I call `http://localhost:4200/first` on the browser address bar the sidebar will simply not load at all.

Comment: If that is the only way to make those sidebars links to work, than the answer to my question is: no, it is not possible to use a default root path '' to a named outlet. And that is the root of the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now you will be able to use the default '' path for the named router outlet.

Comment: Very good!!! That's exactly what I wanted to!! And I was near to the solution, instead of using this `['']`, I just needed to do this `[]`. The reason one works and the other not is totally counter-intuitive to me but, at least it can be done. Thanks a lot! ;)